# html to jade error when contains <pre>

Tags: html, pug

I have some static html documents, and I want to convert them into Jade. I tried [html2jade](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2jade) in npm, everything is OK except this: the `<pre>` elements in html convert empty, can someone help me?

The html code looks like this:

```html
<pre><code>&lt;p&gt;Hello&lt;/p&gt;&lt;span&gt;Hello Again&lt;/span&gt;</code></pre>
```

The result is:

```
pre.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write that a couple different ways in Jade.  Here are two different methods. The first takes advantage of Jade's automatic escaping while the second uses HTML entities instead.

Automatic escaping:

```
pre
    code= '<p>Hello</p><span>Hello Again</span>'
```

HTML entities:

```
pre
    code &lt;p&gt;Hello&lt;/p&gt;&lt;span&gt;Hello Again&lt;/span&gt;
```